# Render to Texture2DArray slices in DirectX11?

Tags: directx, textures, directx11

I would like to set a slice of a `Texture2DArray` as a render target in D3D/DirectX11. It's not clear how to do this.

What I'm looking for is the DirectX equivalent of `glFramebufferTextureLayer()`, which sets a slice of a `GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT` as a texture resource of a Framebuffer Object.

In D3D11, you set a render target using `ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets`, and you can set a `Texture2DArray` resource view as a render target. However, the only way I see to select which slice of the texture is painted is to use the `SV_RenderTargetArrayIndex` semantic in an HLSL geometry shader. (The semantic is only available in a geometry shader).

My pipeline doesn't have a geometry shader, and I don't know at compile time which primitive type I will be rendering - I'm reading models out of input files. It seems like, to add a passthrough geometry shader I would need one shader program for every possible primitive type (terrible).

The desired output slice will not change between rendering passes. Is there no way to set a slice of a `Texture2DArray` as a render target without using a geometry shader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create separate render target views for every slice and then set it using `ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets`.

```
D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC desc;
desc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
desc.Texture2D.MipSlice = D3D11CalcSubresource(0, arraySlice, mipLevels);
```

[Information about subresources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/overviews-direct3d-11-resources-subresources).

Comment: Yup, that works. Thanks!  edit: what I actually did was create an array of Texture2DArray targets, with the start slice set to the i'th slice:
  RenderTarget = new ID3D11RenderTargetView*[targets];
  for(USHORT i=0;i<targets; i++) {
  srtDesc.Format = sTexDesc.Format;
  srtDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DARRAY;
  srtDesc.Texture2DArray.MipSlice = 0;
  srtDesc.Texture2DArray.ArraySize = 1;
  srtDesc.Texture2DArray.FirstArraySlice = i;
  hr = m_pd3dDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(m_pInputView, &srtDesc, &RenderTarget[i]);
}